# A simple finding something in an array

Tags: python

So I've been trying to make a program "how to find if a value is stored in a variable or not".
I did this but it doesn't work, it always says that it is not found even tho its inside the variable

```
a = [2,5,7,9,11]

cari = input("Input the value : ")
ketemu = False
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if cari == a[i]:
        ketemu = True
        break

if ketemu:
  print("Value: ", cari, "found it")
else:
  print("Value: ", cari, "not found")
```

Comment: You have to convert the input to int

Comment: `input()` returns a string value.  The string `"5"` is not equal to integer `5`.

Comment: No need for that loop. `ketemu = int(input("Input the value : ")) in a` then your print statements

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the result of `input` from string to `int`.

```
cari = int(input("Input the value : "))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, tried it and it worked. Why is it have to be like that if you can please answer me ? Appreciate it a lot :D

Comment: @Wenky `input` returns a string and your list contains ints. An `int` will never be equal to a string.

Comment: It is like that because python does not make assumptions for you. You might want to have digits as strings. *Explicit is better than implicit*

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you written only `input()` which is taken as string when you enter the input. For example, if you put 5 as input, `cari` will be '5' and not 5. So change it from `input()` to `int(input())`. Code:

```
a = [2,5,7,9,11]

cari = int(input("Input the value : "))
ketemu = False
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if cari == a[i]:
        ketemu = True
        break

if ketemu:
  print("Value: ", cari, "found it")
else:
  print("Value: ", cari, "not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification to your code that will result the correct out come.

```
a = [2,5,7,9,11]

cari = int(input("Input the value : "))
ketemu = False
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if cari == a[i]:
        ketemu = True
        break

if ketemu:
  print(f"Value: {cari} found it")
else:
  print(f"Value: {cari} not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add the datatype in which you get your answer. If you're getting **integer** then put `int(input())` and when you get **string values** then put `str(input())` according to your query:

```
cari = int(input("Input the value : "))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify the checking loop.

```
a = [2,5,7,9,11]
cari = int(input("Input: "))
if(cari in a):
    print(f"{cari} found")
else:
    print(f"{cari} NOT found")
```